# Hibernate Unidirectional ManyToMany Update Target Constituent Relation

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many, spring-data-jpa

There is a unidirectional `ManyToMany` mapping between `Role` and `Privilege` with `Role` as the owning entity like so

`Role`

```
@Entity
public class Role extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private Integer roleId;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    @JoinTable(name = "role_privilege", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_privilege_id", referencedColumnName = "privilege_id")})
    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.DETACH,
                CascadeType.MERGE,
                CascadeType.REFRESH,
                CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Privilege.class)
    private Collection<Privilege> privilegeCollection;

    @Transient
    private Collection<Privilege> parentPrivilegeCollection;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "roleId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<User> userCollection;

    public Role() {
    }
    //getters,setter,hashcode,equals removed for brevity
}
```

`Privilege`

```
@Entity
public class Privilege extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "privilege_id")
    private Integer privilegeId;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 150)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "friendly_name")
    private String friendlyName;
    @JoinTable(name = "privilege_hierachy", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_privilege", referencedColumnName = "privilege_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "child_privilege", referencedColumnName = "privilege_id")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Privilege> privilegeCollection;

    public Privilege() {
    }
}
```

## The Problem

Whenever i set updated list of privileges  in a role and update, the join table is successfully updated without removing either target or owning entity, and that is desired result. The problem is on update it also affect another self join table in `Privilege` called `privilege_hierachy` which is not what is expect.

Is it possible for hibernate to only update the `Role`-`Privilege` mant-to-many relationship and let other relation unchanged.

Spring Data Jpa is used for data persistence

Comment: please add the method where you perform the update

Comment: Spring Data Jpa repository is used for data persistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are updating the privileges by (removing old privileges and) adding new ones. If you do that, clearly, the second join table (the self-referencing table) could be updated with new rows, based on what you are passing.

I see that for the self-referencing table, Privilege, you are not setting cascade type. It defaults to no operation, and that sounds like what you want. But my guess is based on what you said *"Whenever i set updated list of privileges in a role"*, and that tells me you are creating new privileges for a role, instead of using existing privileges and associate them with the role.

Comment: Thanks it worked, my mistake was as you said, `"...updating the privileges by (removing old privileges and) adding new ones."`